# Why does VS Code not offer methods with autocompletion?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that VS Code doesn't know very many methods and doesn't offer them at autocompletion, for instance:

[image]
[image]

Did I break something? No one's ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is not a statically typed language, so a IDE or Text editor cannot infer what is the type of your variables. In some cases, it does infer, when you use classes, for instance, but note that it is not a limitation of vscode, it is a limitation of dynamically typed languages, like Javascript.
 I suggest that you take a look at TypeScript, a language that can be transpiled to Javascript and that let you statically type you variables, providing the ability to have this kind of feature.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: PhpStorm perfectly complements JS method. Why does it work there?